# counting occurence of factor levels for multiple variables and summarising results in one table

Tags: r

This is my first post here and I am very new to programming and R. so please excuse any stupiditys.

I have the following dataframe:

```
a <- data.frame("sickness1" = c(1,1,2,3,3,5,6, 4, 4, 4),
                "sickness2" = c(NA, NA, 3, 3, 4, 6, 1, 2, 5, 6),
                "sickness3" = c(NA, NA, 3, 4, 4, 6, 1, 2, 5, 6),
                "sickness4" = c(NA, NA, 6, 3, 4, 6, 1, 2, 5, 6))
```

each row represents one case. each column is a ordered factor-variable. I transformed the variables to factors like this (using a tip I found on stackoverflow!):

```
a[] <- lapply(a, factor,
             levels = c(1:6),
             labels = c(3, 25, 50, 75, 97, 100))
```

I would like to get the following output:

```
  percent   sickness1           sickness2    sickness3       sickness4
1       3          1                1            1            2
2      25          1                1            1            1
3      50          2                1            1            2
4      75          1                2            1            3
5      97          1                1            1            1
6     100          2                2            3            1
```

I already found a solution which is very longwinded:

```
# counting
ab <- ldply(lapply(a, count))

#getting it into the right format
ab2 <- dcast(
    data = ab,
    formula = x ~ .id,
    value.var = "freq")

# changing the name of the first column
colnames(ab2)[1] <- "percent"

#deleting row 7 cause it contains the NAs which I dont want to have
ab2 <- ab2[-7,]
ab2
```

is there any faster and easier way to do this? like just using ddply in some way??
the output which summary(a) gives me is too messy, and I dont know how I could manipulate it to look the way I want it to. Also the real data I am working with is way bigger and I have to do this sort of thing many times....

Comment: I guess it would, generally, be more helpful to have such data in a 2 column "data.frame" (here [sickness percent]); then you could just call `table(mydataframe)`. E.g. `table(data.frame(pct = c(5,10,15,10,15,5,10,10,20,25), sickness = c(1,1,1,2,2,3,4,4,4,4)))`

Comment: in the form you are suggesting infromation is lost. What would be possible is a 3 column long data format, so another column for the values, and then again it doesnt work with table(mydataframe). to explain a bit more about the actual data, each row is a institution, so for example a hospital and the percents are percent-ranges, and each institution rates how many of their patients have sickness 1, sickness 2 and so on

Comment: I see; yet (unless memory is an issue) a "data.frame" like `reshape(a, direction = "long", varying = list(1:4), sep = "", times = names(a))` could store the necessary info and is easily manipulated. (In this case, you would have to explicitly state the two columns inside the call to `table`.)  I hope I'm not misunderstanding what you're saying

Comment: what you are saying is right, if I add another column to a for the institution, I can do the following: b2 <- melt(a, id.vars = "institution")
table(b2[2:3])   the result is a table which has the factor levels as columns and the sickness as rows, which is the upside down version of what I want but still good ( I wanted the levels as rows and the sickness as columns)

Comment: just found out that I could transpose the resulting table to get what I wanted... the only thing which is not what I wanted is that it says "variable" on top

Comment: @grrgrrbia You could use `as.data.frame.matrix(t(table(b2[2:3])))`

Comment: very nice :) thanks alot. so to sum up. If I include the number of the institution in my original dataframe a. another option is to go:                                                         `b2 <- melt(a, id.vars = "institution")`                         `atable <- as.data.frame.matrix(t(table(b2[2:3])))`

Comment: You could, also, just do `table(b2[[3]], b2[[2]])` or `table(b2[3:2])`. And you can change "dimnames" the way you want to.

Comment: ah yeah because I want the 3rd element in b2 to be the rows, just changing the order of naming, very clever :), learned so much from you guys, much appreciated!

Comment: ok gonna accept akruns answer now, even though I would like to accept both alexis_laz and akrun :), thanks alot guys!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may try:

```
 un1 <- as.character(sort(unique(unlist(a, use.names=FALSE))))
 data.frame(percent=un1,do.call(cbind,
          lapply(a, function(x) table(factor(x, levels=un1)))))
```

Comment: thanks alot! very elegent solution. Kinda hard to understand for me at first, but unwrapping it peace by peace I got it. Learned about some new functions now, even though I still dont understand do.call exactly even after reading some about it. I am gonna wait before I accept your answer though because I want to hear other solutions :). hope thats ok

Comment: @grrgrrbia Yes, it is okay.  The `a`, I used is after the `a[] <- lapply(a, factor,..)` step.  I think that step could be also avoided.

Answer (score 1):

ok so I found out that there are two possible solutions:

Nr1 by akrun:

```
un1 <- as.character(sort(unique(unlist(a, use.names=FALSE))))
 data.frame(percent=un1,do.call(cbind,
          lapply(a, function(x) table(factor(x, levels=un1)))))
```

Nr.2 by alexis_laz:

given I could easily make the data look like this: (which is just the above a data frame with a column added for the institution)

```
a <- data.frame("institution" = c(1:10), "sickness1" = c(1,1,2,3,3,5,6, 4, 4, 4),
                "sickness2" = c(NA, NA, 3, 3, 4, 6, 1, 2, 5, 6),
                "sickness3" = c(NA, NA, 3, 4, 4, 6, 1, 2, 5, 6),
                "sickness4" = c(NA, NA, 6, 3, 4, 6, 1, 2, 5, 6))

a[-1] <- lapply(a[-1], factor,
                levels = c(1:6),
                labels = c("0 to 3%","4-25%", "25-50%", "51-75%","76-97%","97-100%"))
```

I could then transform this wide data form into long data format like this:

```
b2 <- melt(a, id.vars = "institution")
```

then the normal table function works:

```
table(b2[[3]], b2[[2]])
```

note that the ordering matters

thanks alot guys!

Answer (score 1):

This is mostly a variation on a theme type answer. Use `stack` and `table` together, like this:

```
as.data.frame.matrix(           ## converts the output to a data.frame
  table(                        ## does the actual tabulation
    stack(                      ## stack makes your data.frame long 
      lapply(a, as.character)), ## but won't work with factors; convert to char
        useNA = "no")           ## we don't want NA values
       )[levels(a[[1]]), ]      ## We want our rows in a nicer order
#     sickness1 sickness3 sickness4 sickness5
# 3           2         1         1         1
# 25          1         1         1         1
# 50          2         2         1         1
# 75          3         1         2         1
# 97          1         1         1         1
# 100         1         2         2         3
```

---

Alternatively, here's a "dplyr" + "tidyr" approach:

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)

a %>% gather(var, val, sickness1:sickness5) %>%     ## make the data long
  mutate(val = factor(val, levels(unlist(a)))) %>%  ## refactor "val" column
  rev %>%                         ## reverse the order of val and var
  table %>%                       ## make your table
  as.data.frame.matrix            ## convert it to a data.frame

#     sickness1 sickness3 sickness4 sickness5
# 3           2         1         1         1
# 25          1         1         1         1
# 50          2         2         1         1
# 75          3         1         2         1
# 97          1         1         1         1
# 100         1         2         2         3
```

Comment: thanks alot! especially for the explanations! there is only one part I dont understand and that is what does the `(.)` mean? does it just mean "use the output from the line before"? is this argument part of the base package or of another package? and there is just one small mistake: in the `gather()` argument the columns are `sickness1:sickness4` not `sickness5`

Comment: @grrgrrbla, the `.` is shorthand for referring to the dataset up to that point of evaluation. I've edited the answer to show how to work without `.`. Also, the mistake in `gather` is yours--not mine. Please review your actual question to see what I mean.

Comment: you are right, sry. I just fixed the op. Thanks alot, learned more useful stuff!